# Simple RPC server will not answer when my client connects

Tags: go, rpc

I took and adapted the example from [Golang RPC](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) to make a simple RPC server as a test run for the real task I want to acheive.  But whatever I have tried I end up with the client getting

`2014/03/21 13:28:41 dialing: dial-http tcp MYPC:61740: unexpected HTTP response: 404 Not Found`

I have tried using `MYPC:0`, `127.0.0.1:61470`, `MYPC:61470` and other variants of that theme for the server. Also have tried locally and on two different computers (Note I am using Go 1.2 on Windows). Usually with Go I find it straight-forward to debug, but even reading the source for the rpc pacakge is not helping this time - however I did pick up the trick of :0 giving an available port.

Server can be run by just running the exe, and Client can be run with the port output by the server  `chat -c -server=127.0.0.1:8082`.

What is actually wrong with the following code?

```
package main

import (
"flag"
"log"
"net"
"net/http"
"net/rpc"
)

type Chat string

func (t *Chat) Msg(msg string, bytes *int) error {
    *bytes = len(msg)
    return nil
}

func main() {

    server := flag.String("server", "", "Server and port")
    client := flag.Bool("c", false, "Make me a client")
    flag.Parse()

    log.Println("Server: ", *server)

    if !(*client) {

        chat := new(Chat)
        rpc.Register(chat)
        l, e := net.Listen("tcp", *server)
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
        }
        log.Println(l.Addr().String())
        go rpc.Accept(l)
        http.Serve(l, nil)

    } else {

        log.Println("Client connecting to", *server)
        // !! The error occurs here
        client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", *server)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("dialing: ", err)
        }

        var reply int
        err = client.Call("Chat.Msg", "Make it so!", &reply)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("chat error:", err)
        }
        log.Println("Msg: returned", reply)
}
}
```

Comment: If net/rpc library is too complex to you, try using much simpler yet powerful library - https://github.com/valyala/gorpc .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing rpc.HandleHTTP() after rpc.Register(chat). Try changing your code to

```
...
rpc.Register(chat)
rpc.HandleHTTP()
...
```

It worked for me this way, I got

```
2014/03/20 18:31:21 Server:  localhost:55209
2014/03/20 18:31:21 Client connecting to localhost:55209
2014/03/20 18:31:21 Msg: returned 11
```

And you don't need `go rpc.Accept(l)`. At least for me it worked without this line.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what was missing. Confirmed, the `Accept` is not required, I think it was left over from attempts to solve the problem.